# Powershell Import - CSV select based on timestamp

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Another question on powershell import CSV options
I have two files in the folder
File1 (most recent)
File 2 ( Second most recent)

I selected most recent file with below command

```
$Filerecentdir = "Dir path"
$Filter = "*.csv"
$Filerecent = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

How do I select file 2 , the second most recent file? All these files contains timestamp as well
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-Skip` parameter:

```
Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
```

**Expanded**
Consider using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to simplify your code. Remember that you are getting an **array** of files, sorted in descending order of `LastAccessTime`; you can always index into that array.

```
$location = @{
    "Path"   = "D:\Path\To\Files"
    "Filter" = "*.csv"
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path @location |
                Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending

$files | Out-Host

$firstFile     = $files | Select-Object -First 1
$firstFileAlso = $files[0]

$secondFile     = $files | Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 1
$secondFileAlso = $files[1]
```

Comment: I get first and third file instead of second 
$Filerecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filter = "*.csv"
$Filerecent = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$FileA =  $Filerecent.name


$Filesecondrecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filtersecond = "*.csv"
$Filesecondrecent = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filesecondrecentdir -Filter $Filtersecond | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
$FileC =  $Filesecondrecent.name.  Is it correct?

Comment: @Divya You need to change yours filter to include a `*` - surprised it's returning anything! Assuming it does, it should return the first and second. You don't need to create a separate set of variables for the `Filesecondrecent`. Please see updated example for a simplification. The `$files | Out-Host` part will print the list, so you can check you are getting the first and second. Remember `$files` will already be a sorted list because you used `Sort-Object`.

Comment: Do you mean the second file is also pointing to Files[0]. then it is loading the first file again $Filerecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filter = "*.csv"
$Filesarray = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending
$Filerecent =  $Filesarray | Select-Object -First 1
$FileA = Import-CSV $Filesarray[0]
$Filesecondrecent = $Filesarray | Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 1
$FileC = Import-CSV $Filesarray[1]. With this, it is still loading 3rd file for FileC

Comment: @Divya No, that's a typo - corrected. No idea why you're getting the 3rd file.

Comment: Yeah, it is either the first file or the third one. It is not considering the second one :) Let me take a closer look and get back. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Okay, I just used Lastwritetime instead of Lastaccesstime, it works correctly now $Filerecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filter = "*.csv"
$Filesarray = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
$Filerecent =  $Filesarray | Select-Object -First 2
$FileA = Import-CSV $Filesarray[0]
$FileC =  Import-CSV $Filesarray[1]

Answer (score 2):

Get second-most recent CSV file:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv |
  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
  Select-Object -Index 1
```

(The 0th index would be the most recent file.)

Comment: When I run with Index 0 and 1, I get 1st and third file instead of second 
$Filerecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filter = "*.csv"
$Filerecent = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Index 0
$FileA =  $Filerecent.name


$Filesecondrecentdir = "D:\TCCTouchpoints\Candidate_Import\inbound"
$Filtersecond = "*.csv"
$Filesecondrecent = Get-ChildItem -Path $Filesecondrecentdir -Filter $Filtersecond | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Index 1
$FileC =  $Filesecondrecent.name

Comment: If that's a question, you need to update your question with what you tried and tell the specific problem you are having. Proper formatting is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Aother one just for fun:

```
$Filerecent = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending)[1]
```

Comment: This is giving me error At line:3 char:109
+ ... e -Descending) [0]
+                    ~~~
Unexpected token '[0]' in expression or statement.
At line:3 char:110
+ ...  -Descending) [0]
+                    ~
Missing type name after '['.
At line:9 char:127
+ ... e -Descending) [1]
+                    ~~~
Unexpected token '[1]' in expression or statement.
At line:9 char:128
+ ...  -Descending) [1]
+                    ~
Missing type name after '['.

Comment: What is the actual line of code that you have on line 3?

Comment: $Filerecent = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Filerecentdir -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending)[1]

Comment: I don't see anything syntacticly wrong with that. I would check the lines around it.